# How to use Laravels spatie/laravel analytics package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-analytics-api

I just downloaded this package for Laravel.

[spatie/laravel-analytics](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics?utm_source=learninglaravel.net)

Its a Google Anayltics package, and I followed all the steps for setting up an account. What I'm having trouble is calling the methods. For example when it says:

> Here is an example to retrieve visitors and pageview data for the current day and the last seven days.

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));
```

I tried doing this in my function like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class DashboardController extends Controller {


        public function index() { 

            $analytics = Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));  
            dd($analytics);

            return view('admin.dashboard-v2');
        }

}
```

Its giving me errors like:

> Non-static method Spatie\Analytics\Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews() should not be called statically

Am I missing something here? I couldn't find any specific documentation online except for the Github ReadMe file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the facade to access the class, you'll need to change `use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;` to `use Analytics;`. That should take care of that error.

If you are going to use `Period::days(7)` then you will need to add `use Spatie\Analytics\Period;` because that's an actual static method, not a facade.

Comment: When I come from work, I will take a look. Thank You.